# Order of messages in chat React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat

I am going back to programming after some time. I wrote chatApp once. Now I want to change something there. For now, new messages on chat shows on the top of messages list. I want make it on the bottom. I guess that I have to do something with state update. Please show me where it was.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: [], messages: [], text: '', name: ''};
}

componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('message', message => this.messageReceive(message));
    socket.on('update', ({users}) => this.chatUpdate(users));
}

messageReceive(message) {
    const messages = [message, ...this.state.messages];
    this.setState({messages});
}

chatUpdate(users) {
    this.setState({users});
}

handleMessageSubmit(message) {
    const messages = [message, ...this.state.messages];
    this.setState({messages});
    socket.emit('message', message);
}

handleUserSubmit(name) {
    this.setState({name});
    socket.emit('join', name);
}

render() {
    return this.state.name !== '' ? (
        this.renderLayout()
    ) : this.renderUserForm()
}

renderLayout() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.App}>
            <div className={styles.AppHeader}>
                <div className={styles.AppTitle}>
                    ChatApp
                </div>
                <div className={styles.AppRoom}>
                    App room
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.AppBody}>
                <UsersList
                    users={this.state.users}
                />
                <div className={styles.MessageWrapper}>
                    <MessageList
                        messages={this.state.messages}
                    />
                    <MessageForm
                        onMessageSubmit={message => this.handleMessageSubmit(message)}
                        name={this.state.name}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

}

Answer (score 3):

just change this handler.

```
messageReceive(message) {
    const messages = [message, ...this.state.messages];
    this.setState({messages});
}
```

in order to append the new message to the bottom.

```
messageReceive(message) {
    const messages = [...this.state.messages, message];
    this.setState({messages});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reverse the array of messages and pass it to the `MessagesList`

```
<MessageList
  messages={this.state.messages.reverse()}
/>
```